# Can you identify this bike/frame? Mt FUJI LTD., serial 1104482

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I've done as much digging as I know how and I simply cannot find any information on this frame, It has a sticker on the lower referencing a shop called "Helens Bicycles" and as far as I'm aware it was sold for bicycle tours. It has caliper brakes and an older style threaded head. I do know the Rock Shoxs are after market and I'm using the rims the bike came with which match the gear shifter etc (Shimano Deore XT light action)

[image]

Comment: A hard-tail Fuji with a badly adjusted saddle pictured from the wrong side (no clear view on the drive train!).

Comment: @Carel I understand that its a commonly asked question and that is why I was hesitant to post this in the first place, I don't particularly care about the make/model of my bike as I was simply curious. But may I enquire, if my saddle is poorly adjusted, how could I rectify the issue? I do prefer the saddle with the nose pointed up slightly.

Comment: Make you already know. Model names are not of much use, honestly. Everything you need to know about the bike you can find out by inspecting it.

Comment: Model name is right there on the bike. It’s a Mt Fuji Ltd SX. Early 90s. Top of Fuji’s line. Probably retailed for over $1000.  Great bike. (And those are cantilever brakes not calipers)

Comment: Closing as a dupe, because you have the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated on the frame, it is an SX Mt. Fuji Ltd. produced by Fuji. It was the top of the line steel MTB model for Fuji in the late 80's and early 90's. Frame is made from Tange Prestige tubing, the top of the line tubing from Tange. It is possible that the decal near the top of the seat tube is a tubing decal, which should say Tange Prestige. It's a very high quality bike.

Answer (score 0):

That was a pretty nice bike, back in the day.  Probably around 1987-1990.  Fuji used high quality Tange steel double butted lightweight tubing for their higher end frames
It would definitely be a nice bike to rehab-renovate if there isn’t any substantial rust on-inside the frame.
I would remove the rack and install a rigid fork at the least.  And maybe replace the crankset with one with a single chainring, like a white industry Eno remove the front derailleur and front shifter.